# how do I fix plot problem with R in Jupyter notebook?

Tags: r, ubuntu, plot, jupyter-notebook, anaconda3

I am using jupyter notebook with r, and I faced a strange problem with the axis.
Jupyter doesn't show the value in the axis. It only shows weird boxes. I have no clue why. I am using r-essential with anaconda on my Ubunutu. I thought it might be a problem with the version of r I am using so I tried to create a new environment with r-base4 still has the same issue. Does anyone have an idea? it happens with every plot in the notebook.

```
plot(x=1:30,y=1:30)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide an [MRE]? Tried to reproduce your error on windows, however everything looked fine. Is it just this plot in particular, or does jupyter-notebook butcher all plots in general?

Comment: Seems like a font issue. Could be that you don't have the font installed that's used for the plot.

Comment: @björn it happens with every plot. even a simple plot(x=1:30 , y=1:30). this problem happens when I am on ubuntu!

Comment: @Bas van der Linden. it might be a font issue. I tried to install this in the environment; conda install -c anaconda font-ttf-ubuntu
but the same issue happens.

Comment: @ Bas van der Linden. Thank you very much. It does fix the problem. I really appreciate it.